# uploadify + asp.net-mvc3 problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

Hy guy.

I really tried to do it work but all im getting is an "IO Error".

Here's the code...

```
    $('#uploaded').uploadify({
        'uploader': '/Scripts/EggScripts/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': '/Scripts/EggScripts/Uploadify/cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Anexar',
        'script':'Interaction/Upload',
        'folder': '/uploads/',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true
    });
```

'

```
    [AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
    public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {}
```

The breakpoint Upload action is not even being reached. I'm not using any Authorize decoration.

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploadify recommends all paths be rooted so perhaps rooting the script param will help?

```
'script':'/Interaction/Upload'
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `Upload` action requires authentication this might not work because Uploadify relies on Flash and cookies are not sent along with the request. Also replace all hardcoded urls in your script with ones generated by url helpers:

```
'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EggScripts/Uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EggScripts/Uploadify/cancel.png")',
...
```

You can also subscribe for different event handlers to try to further debug:

```
$('#uploaded').uploadify({
    ...

    onComplete : function() {

    },
    onOpen : function() {

    },
    onError : function (event, id, fileObj, errorObj) {

    }
});
```

Another thing to try is to put a breakpoint in the `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax` to see if some exception is thrown during the execution of the request on the server.